# Pre-installed Internet Explorer 10 Disapperead

Tags: windows-8, internet-explorer

I have installed Windows 8 32-bit/x86 Pro.

I had two versions of IE on my desktop : IE 9 and IE 10.

Somehow, IE 10 got accidentally uninstalled and I am unable to re-install it.

Later, I tried to install it again but with no effort.

How do I able to successfully re-install IE 10 again?

Comment: What exactly have you tried already to restore/reinstall it?

Comment: I am not able to find ie-10 for installation. Searched google but no way lead to satisfactory results.

Comment: Have you tried a [System Restore](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/restore-refresh-reset-pc) yet?

Comment: How exactly did you manage to get both IE9 and IE10 installed, IE9 doesn't even run IE9, or it shouldn't be able to since IE10 cannot be reverted to any previous version under Windows 8.

Comment: You mean windows 8 dosen't even run IE9, not IE9 doesn't even run IE9 I think

Answer (score 0):

In the [traditional, not PC settings] control panel, go to the 'Programs and Features' section. On the left, click the link labeled 'Turn Windows Features On or Off.' One of the items in the list is "Internet Explorer 10". Check the box next to it, hit okay, and let it reinstall. Afterwards, reboot your computer.

Note: If it is already checked, uncheck it to fully uninstall it, then repeat the aforementioned steps to reinstall it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you got confused between IE 10's desktop mode and Modern UI App mode. Its the same browser. IE 10 Desktop looks quite like IE 9, but it isn't IE 9.

First check if you have another browser installed (Chromer? Firefox?) If so go to Control panel -> Default Programs and set IE as your Default browser. Upon that you will be able to access it as a Modern UI App if you start it from the Start Screen and in the familiar Desktop mode if you start it from the Desktop.